# Iperf3 C# Automation Issue

Tags: c#, process, iperf

I am trying to automate iperf3 using c#. The problem is that for some reason the iperf3 output is redirected once the iperf test is done and does not redirect it in real time.

```
public void RunIperf()
{
    {
        sortOutput = new StringBuilder();

        this.dummyProcess .OutputDataReceived += CaptureOutput;
        this.dummyProcess .ErrorDataReceived += CaptureError;

        this.dummyProcess .Start();
        this.dummyProcess .BeginOutputReadLine();
        this.dummyProcess .BeginErrorReadLine();
        this.dummyProcess .WaitForExit();
    }

    static void CaptureOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowOutput(e.Data, ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
}
```

This code works for iperf2 wherein I get data on my console in real time but not for iperf3. I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: On further investigation it seems that iperf3 has an issue of storing the output in the stdout buffer. I am wondering there is anyway to flush that information out of the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `--forceflush` flag to iperf3.

Comment: For all future people, currently `--forceflush` flag is support only on **Linux** IPerf